# rust: how to write an `impl` with callbacks that refers to external values

Tags: struct, rust, closures

I've started dabbling in Rust days ago and have come across the following problem: I have discovered [a library](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/ttf-parser) that allows me to turn font outlines to SVG; on the user side, part of the code looks like the below; 
observe that I have added a constant `SCALE` here that is not present in the original example code that came with said library:

```rust
const SCALE: f32 = 0.5;
struct Builder<'a>(&'a mut svgtypes::Path);
impl ttf::OutlineBuilder for Builder<'_> {
  fn move_to( &mut self, x: f32, y: f32 ) { self.0.push_move_to(
    ( x  * SCALE ) as f64,
    ( y  * SCALE ) as f64 ); }
  ... }

...

let mut builder = Builder(path_buf);
```

the `builder` object is then passed to a function that does the heavy lifting and calls back into the implementation's method. So far, so good: I'd like to scale the paths, and the above code does that. BUT as it stands, I need to define a `const` to do that because Rust doesn't allow methods to refer to outside values. However, I'd like to make the scaling factor dynamic based on properties of the font in question.

Now, say, in JavaScript, I'd maybe use a factory function with a closure over `scale` to do that, or one could just add a property to the object identified as `self`—there's any number of ways to solve this in scripting languages. None of the above seems to be straightforward in Rust. Would it be possible to perhaps declare a new kind of structure that accepts an additional parameter, as in

```rust
struct Builder<'a>(&'a mut svgtypes::Path, scale: f32 );
impl ttf::OutlineBuilder for Builder<'_> {
  fn move_to( &mut self, x: f32, y: f32 ) { self.0.push_move_to(
    ( x  * self.scale ) as f64,
    ( y  * self.scale ) as f64 ); }
  ... }
```

? Needless to say the above code won't compile.

Comment: Why can't you add a property to builder? You'd have to change the struct from a tuple Struct to a c style Struct of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it be possible to perhaps declare a new kind of structure that accepts an additional parameter

Yes, it would! The sample code defines `Builder` as a [Tuple Struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.9.0/book/structs.html#tuple-structs), kind of like a struct with unnamed fields. While you can add another element to this, which you would refer to as `self.1`, it is probably best to switch to a normal struct:

```
struct Builder<'a> {
    path: &'a svgtypes::Path, 
    scale: f32
};
```

Then you can access the scale as `self.scale`:

```
impl ttf::OutlineBuilder for Builder<'_> {
    fn move_to( &mut self, x: f32, y: f32 ) { self.path.push_move_to(
    ( x  * self.scale ) as f64,
    ( y  * self.scale ) as f64 ); }
... }
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this is what I did after reading one more sample code from the same source.